# Field definition in custom field and varchar_ascii

Tags: 8

When making custom field and doing field definitions for string I came upon this setting.

```
  'type' => $field_definition->getSetting('is_ascii') === TRUE ? 'varchar_ascii' : 'varchar',
```

I just cant find a reference what would it be if a field definition is set to "varchar_ascii" is it something to do with "Collation" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc block of [database.api.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/8.6.x)/[Schema API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/group/schemaapi/8.6.x) state:

> A special `varchar_ascii` type is also available for limiting machine name field to US ASCII characters.

You can see its implementation in [Schema::createFieldSql()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Driver%21mysql%21Schema.php/function/Schema%3A%3AcreateFieldSql/8.6.x) of the MySQL abstraction layer.

So yes, it changes the default UTF-8 character set/collation to ASCII.